# Namespacing and function declaration types

Tags: javascript

I'm currently starting to work on existing project. We have global namespace object `FOO` and a helper to create a nice namespace:

```
var FOO = FOO || {};
//...
FOO.namespace = function (name) {
    var parts = name.split('.'),
        parent = FOO,
        i;

    // strip redundant leading global
    if (parts[0] === "FOO") {
        parts = parts.slice(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 1) {
        // create a property if it doesn't exist
        if (typeof parent[parts[i]] === "undefined") {
            parent[parts[i]] = {};
        }
        parent = parent[parts[i]];
    }

    return parent;
};
```

Because there are many submodules spread out over different files being worked on from different people I noticed different patterns on declaring new submodules.

#### A: direct creation

```
FOO.modulename = {

    someMethod: function (param) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### B: Local alias with direct assignment

```
var modulename = FOO.namespace('modulename');
modulename.someMethod = function (param) {
    // ...
}
```

#### C: Objectliteral assignment to submodule

```
var modulename = FOO.namespace('modulename');
FOO.modulename = {
    someMethod: function (param) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, A is obviously not the right way but what about the other options (and I guess i will discover at least 3 more ways to do it). They all achive the same thing and all work, but **which method is the most "correct" one?**

Comment: I'd say all of them and none of them are 'correct'. Consistency is the most important thing? At least with B and C your namespacing function can warn you of name collisions.

Comment: I was looking for this:  var FOO = FOO || {};  This seems like a very obvious means to declare an object/namespace without knowing if it already exists..  Perfect, thanks.

Comment: I was looking for this:  var FOO = FOO || {};  This seems like a very obvious means to declare an object/namespace without knowing if it already exists..  -- edit -- Does not work.  You have to reference the global window object like this, var FOO = window.FOO || {}; otherwise you get a ReferenceError error.